# INDEX MATCH multiple criteria to include date

Tags: excel

I have a table with few types of items buying in and selling out. I created a formula which calculates the total selling price when item was sold.

[image]

How do I include a date criteria in the formula so that it can capture an existing item with a new price? Thank you.

> *ADDED QUESTION TO THE ANSWER:*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula will do it.

This is a normal formula. Do NOT array-enter:

```
=IF(D10,LOOKUP(2,1/((B$2:B10=B10)*(C$2:C10>0)),C$2:C10)*D10,"")
```

Note: this does not use the date, but instead uses the latest pricing data.

Comment: @user2652375 Glad I could help.

Comment: Thank you so much, Excel Hero! As I'm a beginner in Excel function, I evaluated your formula and got the help of LOOKUP function. I added my doubt in lower part of my Question. Am I correct of how your LOOKUP function works?

Comment: @user2652375 I don't see the update to your question. What is your doubt?

Comment: @user2652375 Yes, what you added to your question is correct. The LOOKUP() function is rather special among the roster of worksheet functions. The easiest way to think about it is that it matches in REVERSE order; so if there are multiple matches, it returns the LAST one. It also has a rare ability to ignore error values in the list it searches. It also has a very rare capability to process arrays without the need to array-enter the formula. And, it has the useful capability to work with an optional associated array to pick the results from. All in all, one of the gems of Excel.

Comment: Thank you so much, Excel Hero. You're really a genius!

Comment: @user2652375 You are welcome. The best thanks you can give me though would be to upvote my answer... :)

Comment: Sorry, I almost forgot to do that. Done!

Comment: @user2652375 Thank you so much!